# How to fetch unique data on multiple column using MongoDB and Java

Tags: java, mongodb

How to fetch the MongoDB collection data unique with two-column emp_country and emp_city and return the array with these two data in the array format.

I need pagination also with country and city. So, when I got unique data, then I can apply pagination as well. Expected output as below mentioned in example and also need for pagination but data should be unique in response.

Sample data:

```
[
   {
      "id":"1",
      "emp_name":"emp1",
      "data":[{
         "emp_country":"country1",
         "emp_city":"city1"
      },
      {
         "emp_country":"country1",
         "emp_city":"city2"
      }]
   },
   {
      "id":"2",
      "emp_name":"emp2",
      "data":[{
         "emp_country":"country2",
         "emp_city":"city2"
      }]
   },
   {
      "id":"3",
      "emp_name":"emp3",
      "data":[{
         "emp_country":"country1",
         "emp_city":"city1"
      }]
   },
   {
      "id":"4",
      "emp_name":"emp4",
      "data":[{
         "emp_country":"country1",
         "emp_city":"city2"
    }]
   }
]
```

Expected output:

```
[
   {
      "emp_country":"country1",
      "emp_city":"city1"
   },
   {
      "emp_country":"country2",
      "emp_city":"city2"
   },
   {
      "emp_country":"country1",
      "emp_city":"city2"
   }
]
```

How to achieve the above result using Java and MongoDB?

Comment: in your collection there are 3 docs this is one doc of collection ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only country and city in your data document
[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gI9akTcM5Yv)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$data"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$data"
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$_id"
    }
  }
])
```

If you have possible more than the field country and city in your data document
[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fcsUWmGZWzM)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$data"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "emp_country": "$data.emp_country",
        "emp_city": "$data.emp_city"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$_id"
    }
  }
])
```

To write it in Java you can do it with `Document` and construct the query, or with the query builder
[See here for examples](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/quickstart/java-aggregation-pipeline/)

Comment: I got the duplicate result when I add one more data with-
{
    "id": "4",
    "emp_name": "emp4",
    "data": {
      "emp_country": "country1",
      "emp_city": "city2"
    }

Comment: i dont see the duplicate, check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/owCza_ocZS7)
There is no document that has the same country AND the same city.If you have data that query doesnt work give that data if you can so to test it.

Comment: I have change data Object to Array in the above example and did not get Result

Comment: ok i updated the answer for the new data, if you change the data its best to do it in another question, or in the same with Edit1 (keeping the old question) (if you have got answers already,here was only 2 its ok,but if were many, the wouldnt make sense with the new data)

Comment: Thanks @Takis_ it is working now as expected. I stuck one more problem if you can answer that also helped. I want to fetch max and min based on salary currency.
Ref- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68993192/how-to-get-max-and-min-value-in-mongodb-based-on-specific-key

Comment: Hi @Takis_, can we acheive this without using aggregation of the mongo template method, use with find() method or any method under mongo repository. Ref-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69077251/how-to-find-distinct-data-in-mongorepository

Comment: if you mean spring-data you can [aggregate with spring-data](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-projections-aggregations) We can't group in find we need to aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

In your example it's unclear what should happen if you have fourth document with data:

```
{
  "id":"4",
  "emp_name":"emp4",
  "data":{
     "emp_country":"country1",
     "emp_city":"city4"
  }
}
```

For a result with 2 lists of unique values of each field you can use `$addToSet`. In your case it would like as this in MongoDB:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        'data.emp_country': {$addToSet: 'data.emp_country'},
        'data.emp_city': {$addToSet: 'data.emp_city'},
    }
}])
```

and the result will look like this:

```
{
    _id: null,
    'data.emp_country': ['country1', 'country2'],
    'data.emp_city': ['city1', 'city2']
}
```

Comment: No , I don't want to get the data in format 'data.emp_country': ['country1', 'country2'].
I need pagination also with country and city so when I got unique data then I can apply pagination as well. expected output as above mentioned in example and also need for pagination. toy have added 4th data that is correct that also possible. but data should be unique in response.