# How to find Distinct Data in MongoRepository

Tags: java, mongodb, jpa, mongodb-query

How to write Custom Query for Mongo DB to get the distinct data Need to write in Java but I need to check if is it possible with the query as well without using aggregation pipeline.
Sample Data:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "empName":"emp1",
      "emp_city":"city1"
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "empName":"emp2",
      "emp_city":"city1"
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "empName":"emp1",
      "emp_city":"city1"
   },
   {
      "id":4,
      "empName":"emp1",
      "emp_city":"city2"
   }
]
```

Expected Output:

```
[
   {
      "empName":"emp1",
      "emp_city":"city1"
   },
   {
      "empName":"emp1",
      "emp_city":"city2"
   },
   {
      "empName":"emp2",
      "emp_city":"city1"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

For what you are trying to archive I would suggest using a group by, by the two fields (empName and emp_city),

Here you have and example https://sqlserverguides.com/mongodb-group-by-multiple-fields/

Comment: I don't want to use the aggregation method, this is the method of the mongo template but I need to use the mongo repository. so is it possible to write a query without using aggregation?

Comment: okay, so that is the only way distinct with multiple fields to use aggregation instead of find() method to achieve the same result? distinct with one field but the response like on the above example is also fine. but when I use a predefined method the return type is List<String> so need to write with a custom query but I don't want to use aggregation method of mongo template

Comment: What you want and what you have available are two different things, the easiest and more maintainable way is by using an aggregate, and I assume that you have and index by those two fields. If you do a distinct field by field you will generate false results because you may ended up with a cartesian product of each set. MongoTemplate also admits custom return types depending on the version if I'm not mistaken. You can always cast from string to your value. The only other version of distinct will be concatenating the fields using a separator, then distinct, then split the result by concat key

Comment: can we use with spring-data without using the mongo template method by using @Query annotation? use any method for the mongo repository instead of the mongo template.

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        empName: "$empName",
        emp_city: "$emp_city"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$_id"
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/d8i7iOuvfsR

Comment: I don't want to use the aggregation method, this is the method of the mongo template but I need to use the mongo repository. so is it possible to write a query without using aggregation?